# Can I split my gulp tasks between different files when using Visual Studio?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, gulp

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 and I have gulpfile that I run with the gulp task manager.

The file is getting bigger and bigger. Is there some way that I can split the tasks into more than one file.  If there is then I would really appreciate a very small example of how I can do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, as the gulp documentation explains: https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/split-tasks-across-multiple-files.md
This is depreciated and will not be supported in gulp 4.0.

gulpfile.js

```
var requireDir = require('require-dir');
var tasks = requireDir('./tasks');
```

Or with `gulp-require-tasks`

gulpfile.js

```
// Require the module.
var gulpRequireTasks = require('gulp-require-tasks');

// Call it when neccesary.
gulpRequireTasks({
  path: __dirname + '/tasks' // This is default
});
```

tasks/one.js

```
module.exports = {
  dep: ['clean:styles'],
  fn: function (gulp, callback) {
    return gulp.src('...')
      .pipe(plugin())
      .dest('...');
  }
};
```